# Extracting and grouping database data to an array

Tags: php, database, arrays, foreach, preg-match

I have a database field called "servers"
This field has a link in each row, this field content:

```
> http://www.rapidshare.com/download1
> http://www.rapidshare.com/download2
> http://www.rapidshare.com/download3
> http://www.megaupload.com/download1
> http://www.megaupload.com/download2
> http://www.megaupload.com/download3
> http://www.fileserve.com/download1
> http://www.fileserve.com/download2
> http://www.fileserve.com/download3
```

I want to create an array with all the server names, and create more array with links inside.
That's how it should be:

> ```
> $servers = array(
>   'rapidshare'        => array(
>       'link1'             => 'http://www.rapidshare.com/download1',
>       'link2'             => 'http://www.rapidshare.com/download2',
>       'link3'             => 'http://www.rapidshare.com/download3'),
>   'megaupload'        =>  array(
>       'link1'             => 'http://www.megaupload.com/download1',
>       'link2'             => 'http://www.megaupload.com/download2',
>       'link3'             => 'http://www.megaupload.com/download3'),
>   'fileserve'         =>  array(
>       'link1'             => 'http://www.megaupload.com/download1',
>       'link2'             => 'http://www.megaupload.com/download2',
>       'link3'             => 'http://www.megaupload.com/download3')
> );
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:  (make sure that domain is actually showing up in $domain variable though because it might be $matches[1]... I can't remember)

```
$newStructure = array();
foreach($links as $link) {
    preg_match("/www\.([^\.])\.com/",$link,$matches);
    $domain = $matches[0];

    $currentLength = count($newStructure[$domain]);
    if($currentLength) {
       $newStructure[$domain]['link'.($currentLength+1)] = $link;
    } else {
       $newStructure[$domain] = array('link1'=>$link);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, masking got along, I could also use some of your code!

Comment: Sure thing.  If you liked it and it helped you, can you accept the answer with the check mark? On Stack overflow when you answer a question and it gets accepted, it increases your rating which helps you get your questions answered in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$server = array(
    'http://www.rapidshare.com/download1',
    'http://www.rapidshare.com/download2',
    'http://www.rapidshare.com/download3',
    'http://www.megaupload.com/download1',
    'http://www.megaupload.com/download2',
    'http://www.megaupload.com/download3',
    'http://www.fileserve.com/download1',
    'http://www.fileserve.com/download2',
    'http://www.fileserve.com/download3'
);

$match = array();
$myarray = array();


foreach($server as $v) {
    // grab server name
    preg_match('/\.(.+)\./', $v, $match);
    $serverName = $match[1];

    // initialize new array if its the first link of that particular server
    if (!isset($myarray[$serverName])) {
        $myarray[$serverName] = array();
    }

    // count server array to check how many links are there, and make next link key 
    $linkKey = 'link' . (count($myarray[$serverName]) + 1);

    // store value
    $myarray[$serverName][$linkKey] = $v;
}

print_r($myarray);
```

Hey maybe this will help you. But i dont see the purpose of those names of the keys (link1,link2 etc..). This wont work on pagination thou.